# Reference a project that is in a submodule from a submodule C#

Tags: c#, git

I want to have the following structure in git / visual studio:

```
Repo A
-Shared project

Repo B
-Client project (Has a reference to shared project)
-I must be able to run / build this solution individually

Repo C
-Web project (Has a reference to shared project)
-I must be able to run / build this solution individually

Repo D (Main visual studio solution that contains each project)
- Repo A (Submodule)
- Repo B (Submodule)
- Repo C (Submodule)
-I must be able to run / build this solution
```

Each repo should be self-contained. (e.g: If I clone the "Repo C", I must be
able to compile it, and the same goes for the Repo D, if I clone it, I must be able
to compile the entire solution.)

The web and client project needs to reference the `Shared` one,
so, I tried adding a submodule to the client / web project that points to 
the shared one but then, when I try to compile the main solution it will fail
since it cannot find the shared project.

Any idea how can I achieve this?

**Nuget is not an option**.

Comment: Have you tried adding separate projects in VS?

Comment: @PraveenM each project has its own solution

Comment: FWIW: [An interesting discussion on if a flat directory tree could be a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721074/can-i-organize-git-submodules-in-a-flat-hierarchy)

Comment: @EfrainBastidasBerrios: Were you able to find a solution to your problem? I might have something on similar lines that needs my attention.

Answer (score 0):

Repo D (here is just a solution that holds set of all projects in it ,its not necessary you will run Repo-D , correct ?).
You will either run Repo-B/Repo-C that to individually. Thus you can just build Repo-D(solution as a whole).

But to check if the shared project is working well,you need to run/execute Repo-B or Repo-C individually (note the shared project[Repo-A] will also get compiled and the references will be added in the bin folder for each of these projects)

Comment: Yep I need to be able to run /build repo d. The problem is that I can't compile neither client nor web projects because their refence shared (and shared is a submodule added inside client / web projects to make them compile)